# Creating new document (entity), adding it to collection

Tags: rest

Suppose we have the collection `/items/` and we want to allow clients to add new items to this collection. Inspired by Rails, I've come to the following: we simply add resource `/items/new`, and the one who wants to add an item first issues `GET /items/new`, receiving empty entity (probably with some default values set), then fills the desired fields and issues `POST /items/`.

- Is this approach good for true REST API? What could be improved/reworked?
- If suddenly this approach is good (and if it's not, anyway):

> Suppose each item has the required field *Title*. It's probably not so good to return some default value in response to `GET /items/new`. 
>   What is better in this case? To return `null` *Title* and return an error when it's POSTed empty? To implement constructor-like logic for `new` resource, asking for required fields, say, in query string? Something else?
>   
>   Thank you.

**UPD.** Just to clarify, using `new` is not about splitting "add" into "allocate" and "write contents" since no action on data store is done on `GET /items/new`. It's meant to be a way to achieve flexibility in entity design: rich client may dynamically render input fields according to what came in response to new. Does that make sense? Or the contract is to be fixed and we need to version the API for the changes like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why first returning an empty item? I'd just let the client POST a new item (including all its properties) to /items/new instead. At least that's the way I remember it being done in Rails ;)

In any case, the additional returning of an empty item serves no use, adds an additional network roundtrip and potentially breaks the REST approach by splitting the "add" operation into "allocate" and "write contents".

If you want to do any uniqueness checks, UID generation etc that can be done just as well (or better) with one "add the complete item" operation.

*Update :* The confusion maybe comes from the fact that the rails controllers both act as REST API as well as controllers for the web UI. This means that some actions are useful in an API (that is used by some application / code)  and some are needed because the presentation layer (used by a human) needs something it can call. 
I wouldn't really consider the "new" action to be useful in an API, but the user does need something he can call to get an empty form.

Comment: I agree. Why to place a constructor-like functionality to data access service. You can place such things within client side.

Comment: @creinig: See [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#creating-new-posts) for an example of such in Rails. It's not splitting "add" into "allocate" and "write contents" since no action on data store is done on `GET /items/new`. It's meant to be a way to achieve flexibility in entity design: rich client may dynamically render input fields according to what came in response to `new`. Does that make sense?

Comment: @starteleport: Ah ok, valid point. But if this is desired, it should be explicitly modeled as two separate actions. The rails tutorial you linked does this as well (actions 'new' and 'create'). It also allows calling "create" without a preceding "new".

Comment: @creinig: So, I just shouldn't fix the precedence? Plus, is it OK that entity contract can change in time without any special notice (like another API version in query string)?

Answer (score 2):

Usually when I create a REST API, I use the singular form of the entity name, so it's

```
api.company.com/item
```

From there if a client want's a particular item, they would do an HTTP GET

```
api.company.com/item/{id}
```

And usually you don't want the verb to be in the URL. so "item/new" is poor design. The standard HTTP methods should be sufficient (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE)

So for your case, I would recommend not doing "item/new" and just let the client do an HTTP POST to

```
api.company.com/item
```

If you're doing XML you give clients an XSD so they know what's required or not. If you're using JSON, it'll probably be documented somewhere.

As for enforcing the required "title" field, I would do validation of all new entities posted to your resource. I assume you have a domain model that the posted data gets mapped to. You can just do your validation and return a HTTP response with status 400, or if your API has custom error response use that.

Here's a [resource](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) I check out pretty often to remember the HTTP status codes and their meaning

Comment: Please see the update in the main post. Is it anything better? Or still a no-no?

Comment: Usually as an API provider, you should not be concerned with the default values shown by the client [(SoC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), that's the domain of the client. If having default values is somehow critical, then you could potentially put in your documentation that clients can call api.company.com/item/{someid} for a template. But if it's not critical, you should really just leave it up to the client.